# Database structure with Entity Framework Core - Discrimination

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following problem:

I'd like to be able sell a few kinds of products in my store.

I have created following infrastructure:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    public Product Parent {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Children {get; set;}
}

public class AudioFile : Product
{
    public string SomeValue {get; set;}
}

public class DocummentFile : Product
{
    public string SomeString {get; set;}
}
```

In fluent mapping I am using discriminator.

So, to Select the amount of documment files without a parent, I am doing something like this:

```
DbContext.DocummentFiles.Count(x=> !x.ParentId.HasValue)
```

It works with Audio files too.

I'd like to select sample dictionary of all children for some audio file with `SomeValue`:

```
DbContext.AudioFiles
    .Where(x => x.ParentId == 222)
    .Select(x => x.Children
        .OfType<AudioFile>()
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.SomeValue));
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I have high CPU usage by the long time, but I have not any result.

Comment: This code is simular, but does not working too:

            var query = from af in DbContext.AudioFiles
                select new AudioFileShortViewModel()
                {
                    AudioFileIdKeyNamePair =
                        af.Children
                            .OfType<AudioFile>()
                            .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(g.Id, g.Key.Name))
                            .ToList()
                };
var result = await result2.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 222);